Write the contents of a .conf file into a variable located in a separate .conf file
I am configuring my hyprland.conf file and I am attempting to do it in a clean and modular fashion. I am trying for a modular fashion so that I can share my dotfiles and someone else can change which components they are using without directly modifying the hyprland.conf file. Near the top of my hyprland.conf file I would like to create variables for use in other parts of the file, such as the keybindings. If I explicitly set the variables, such as $terminal = kitty, they work fine. However, when I attempt to populate the variable with the contents of a separate .conf file, it doesn't seem to populate.
The terminal.conf file that I am attempting to retrieve the contents of contains only the following:
kitty

The code I am using to populate the variable in my hyprland.conf file is as follows:
exec-once = export TERMINAL="$(cat ~/.config/hypr/settings/terminal.conf)"

If I open a terminal and enter
echo "$(cat ~/.config/hypr/settings/terminal.conf)"

I get
kitty

as a response, which is what I am expecting to see in the variable.
For the keybinding section of my hyprland.conf file, I am attempting to use the variable as follows:
bind = SUPER, T, exec, "$TERMINAL"

However, when I use that keybind to open a terminal, nothing happens. Therefore, I attempted to check the contents of the $TERMINAL variable in my hyprland.conf file by executing the following command:
exec = echo "$TERMINAL" >> ~/.config/hypr/hyprland.conf

All it adds to the file are empty lines. What am I doing wrong?

Well, I thought I had already tried the following, but apparently I was mistaken. The correct way to achieve what I am trying to do is as follows:
$TERMINAL = $(cat ~/.config/hypr/settings/terminal.conf)

This sets the variable within the hyprland.conf file. In order to use the variable, for example, in a keybind, it is accomplished as follows:
bind = SUPER, T, exec, $TERMINAL

